# How to get angle from point1 to point2 in earth

Tags: java, geography

I've spend much time internet for finding a way to do this. By exist documention I wrote below code, But it does not show correct angle. 
What's problem?
 [image]

```
private double angleFromCoordinate(double lat1, double long1, double lat2,
            double long2) {

        double dLon = (long2 - long1);

        double y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
        double x = Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1)
                * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon);

        double brng = Math.atan2(y, x);

        brng = Math.toDegrees(brng);

        brng %= 360;
        // brng = 360 - brng;

        return brng;
    }
```

**UPDATED**
    result of below code:

```
int angle = (int) angleFromCoordinate(36.288024, 59.615656
                    , 39.033659, 48.662504);
angle is '58'
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a pair of latitudes and longitudes that you are passing to this method, along with the output that you expect, and the output that you really get?

Comment: input of angleFromCoordinate is latitude and longtude and not degree, Should I convert to radius?

Comment: Those numbers - 36.288024, 59.615656 and so on - are a number of degrees.  Yes, you should convert them to radians, as described in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods `Math.cos` and `Math.sin` take a number of radians for their arguments.  You are passing degrees into this method.  You need to convert your degrees into radians at the start of the method.

```
private double angleFromCoordinate(double lat1, double long1, double lat2,
        double long2) {
    double lat1Rad = Math.toRadians(lat1);
    double long1Rad = Math.toRadians(long1);
    double lat2Rad = Math.toRadians(lat2);
    double long2Rad = Math.toRadians(long2);
```

then use the new variables `lat1Rad` and so on for the remaining mathematics.

Comment: It was bit tip but useful, Thank you